# Facebook Api Error Missing Argument

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
require_once "src/facebook.php";

 $facebook = new Facebook();

 $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$app_access_token = $app_id . '|' . $app_secret;

$response = $facebook->api( '/user_id/notifications', 'POST', array(

        'template' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',

        'href' => '',

        'access_token' => $app_access_token
    ) );
```

this is my working code. But Im getting error.

Code Is working fine but getting this error.

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Facebook::__construct(), called in 
/xx/xx/xxxx.php on line 6 and defined in/home1/x/xx/xx/facebook.php on line 57
```

Comment: RTFM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install

Answer (score 0):

Facebook class instantiation should happen this way

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true
  ));
```

`Facebook::__construct()` function needs first param as array of configuration data.

Move your

```
$app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";    
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

as

```
$app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";    
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' =>  $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
  ));
```